# Prove that if a sequence converges then $\lim_{k \to \infty} kb_k = 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

We have that $(b_n)$ is a sequence of decreasing, non-negative real terms. We wish to show that if $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} b_n$ converges then it must be the case that $$\lim_{k \to \infty} k.b_k = 0$$

I'm stuck on this problem, I want to show this using a contradiction (assuming the limit is not zero) and showing that that contradicts the Cauchy Criterion.

Thanks.

Comment: It is a well known theorem..

Comment: It isn't well known to me - the fact it is well know doesn't help me prove it unfortunately :(

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** [Cauchy Condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test).Can you conclude using this?

**Edit:** $\displaystyle \sum 2^n b_{2^n} $ converges since $\displaystyle  \sum b_n $ converges, and thus $ 2^n b_{2^n} \to 0. $ Now for $ 2^n < k < 2^{n+1} $,

$$ 2^n b_{2^{n+1}}    \leq k b_{k} \leq 2^{n+1} b_{2^n}$$

so $n b_n \to 0.$

Comment: How to prove $2^nb_{2^{n+1}} \to 0$?

Comment: Dear Madhan, use necessary condition for convergence of series. Best,

Comment: Yes i figured it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n=b_{n}-b_{n+1}\ge 0$. Then $\sum b_n<\infty$, implies that $b_n\to 0$ and hence $a_n\to 0$. Now 
$$
b_n=(b_n-b_{n+1})+(b_{n+1}-b_{n+2})+\cdots=\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k,
$$ 
and hence
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty ka_k.
$$
But as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty ka_k<\infty$, then 
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=n}^\infty ka_k=0$. However
$$
nb_n=\sum_{k=n}^\infty na_k \le \sum_{k=n}^\infty ka_k,
$$
and therefore $nb_n\to 0$.